# Return the detail of a nested form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a "collection_select" of invoices and I want that when selecting an invoice I return the detail of it, then paint a table with the details in a view.

My problem is that I do not know how to call ajax the detail of a nested form.

Comment: Hello @Derlis and welcome to StackOverflow. Your qeustion is too broad. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the invoice_id from the collection_select by jquery

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/invoice/' + $('#dropDownId').val(),
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(res){
    $('#your_invoice_display_area').html(res);
  }
})
```

in your controller:

```
def show
  @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render json: @invoice, include: :invoice_items}
  end
end
```

the json data will be something like this:

```
{"invoice":{"id":35,"bill_to":"Mr. X","address":"Address details","custom_date":"2017-07-05","subtotal":"5627.0","discount":null,"tax":null,"number":"INV_00035","created_at":"2017-04-05T16:52:04.071+06:00","updated_at":"2017-05-03T13:50:01.308+06:00","company":"Company Name","phone":"12345667","email":"email@gmail.com","billing_period":"","in_word":null,"total":"5627.0"}}
```

then, in the success function in your ajax call, you can use the json to paint a table.

first, make an empty table giving ids to the each field. Then use jquery to add the values.

```
success: function(res){
  $("#bill_to").html(res["invoice"]["bill_to"]);
  $("#address").html(res["invoice"]["address"]);
}
```

Hope that helps. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. My question is just how to return in json format first and then paint a table with the result in the view.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Hi @Rifatul, your answer was very helpful, but how do I get all the details of a header? For example, the invoice I chose has 5 items and I want all, this method only returns the first one.

Comment: updated the answer again. You have to include the associations. For my case, it was invoice_items. my Invoice has_may invoice_items.